# Translation of System.Windows.Input.Key enum in Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, translation

I'm currently working on some code that handles keyboard shortcuts in my Silverlight 4 application. I want to create a manage window where users can define custom keyboard shortcuts if they do not want to use the default ones. However some keys have a different translation in some languages (e.g. Home, Del, ...). Of course I want to translate those texts so that every user understands the keyboard shortcuts correctly.

Is there something like a built-in translation for something like this? I'm thinking of something like the way DateTime behaves. If I work with DateTimes the texts for days or months are automatically defined through the systems Culture settings.

```
string dateTimeTest = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

On a German system this results in the text "Freitag, 20. Juli 2012".

Is there something comparable like this available for keys as well? Or do I have to translate all needed keys manually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you're looking for something like [GetKeyNameText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646300(v=vs.85).aspx), but for Silverlight, right? I *think* it doesn't exist, but I would be happy to see an answer showing that I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Yeah, that pretty much sums it up. Seems exactly like what I'm looking for. But as you said I'd need it in Silverlight. But thanks for that link, I think now I know a bit more that I can use in several Google searches :-)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `ToString` overload that takes a culture - having one is a sign that you can get localised output. I don't think you can in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the input ChrisF, I think you're right about that. I decided to manually translate the values I need. At least not every value of the Key enum has to be translated because only some of them actually have different names for other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most language support, you have to do this yourself in Silverlight. Of course, there are ways to make that easier.

If you're app is running out-of-browser (OOB), in Silverlight 4, you could deploy a COM object that wraps the native call to [`GetKeyNameText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); in Silverlight 5, OOB or elevated in-browser app, you could P/Invoke it directly.

However, if you are running inside the browser without elevated privileges, your options are greatly diminished. I am not aware of any libraries (commercial or otherwise) that provide this feature, so you're going to have to create your own localizable resources and associated methods to achieve this.

You may find the [W3C guidance on accessibility in Silverlight](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20-TECHS/silverlight.html) to be a useful resource.